# How to enforce monotonicity for (regression) model outputs in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, regression

I am currently working on a problem where I provide a neural network with an input variable ***a***, and another input ***x*** which is a  monotonically increasing sequence of N numbers.

So my network would basically looks something like this:

```
a_input = Input(shape=[1], name='a')
x_input = Input(shape=[N], name='x')
nn = concatenate([a_input, x_input])
nn = Dense(100, activation='relu')(nn)
nn = Dense(N, activation='relu')(nn)
model = Model(inputs=[a_input, x_input], outputs=[nn])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")
```

I perform a regression over the input space (where for each ***a*** the sequence ***x*** is unique), and I want the network to output a monotonically increasing sequence of (non-negative) *N* numbers for each set of inputs ***a*** and ***x***.

Now, I have noticed that so far my outputs are not strictly speaking monotonic, but sort of look like they are if you 'zoom out'. By this I mean, for a given choice of ***a*** and ***x***,  if I want my output array to look like:

```
[0, 0.5, 0.51, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9, 1.],
```

I might instead get:

```
[0.001, 0.5, 0.48, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9, 1.].
```

Hence, I would like to know if there are standard ways, or specific tools already available in Keras, to constrain models to only output monotonically increasing sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enforce non-negative outputs, use a non-negative activation such as ReLU or sigmoid in your output layer.

I am not aware of any *neural* method to enforce monotonicity in your output, but in my opinion a sensible approach would be to change the output representation  to make the network predict the difference between two consecutive elements. For example, you could transform your output array:

`a=[0, 0.5, 0.51, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9, 1.]`

to:

`b=[0, 0.5, 0.01, 0.19, 0.05, 0.15, 0.1]`

with `b[0] = a[0]` and `b[i] = a[i]-a[i-1]` for `i>0`. Within this context, it would make sense to use a recurrent layer as the output layer, since each output unit now depends on the previous ones. Your original representation can be easily recovered as `a[0] = b[0]` and `a[i] = b[i]+a[i-1]` for `i>0`, and the resulting sequence will be monotonically increasing because each output `b[i]` is non-negative.

---

**UPDATE 1**. The LSTM should return the full sequence. You could try building the model as follows:

```
a_input = Input(shape=[1], name='a')
x_input = Input(shape=[N], name='x')
nn = concatenate([a_input, x_input])
nn = Dense(100, activation='relu')(nn)
nn = Dense(N, activation='relu')(nn)
nn = Lambda(lambda x: x[..., None])(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps=N, input_dim=1)
nn = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, activation='relu')(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps=N, output_dim=1)
nn = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.squeeze(x, axis=-1))(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, N)
model = Model(inputs=[a_input, x_input], outputs=[nn])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")
```

---

**UPDATE 2**. The LSTM with one hidden unit might not be powerful enough. I am not sure if this will help, but you could try adding another LSTM layer with more units (i.e. 10) before the last one:

```
...
nn = Lambda(lambda x: x[..., None])(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps=N, input_dim=1)
nn = LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps=N, output_dim=10)
nn = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, activation='relu')(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps=N, output_dim=1)
nn = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.squeeze(x, axis=-1))(nn)  # Output shape=(batch_size, N)
...
```

Comment: I like your idea and think it makes sense to me, with the caveat that I have little experience with using RNNs. 

As I understand, you suggest for each training sample, x_train = {_a_, _[x0, x1,..., xN]_}, I convert my y_train to y_train' = {y_train[0], y_train[1]-y_train[0],...}?  

When building the model, would it then suffice to just change the last Dense(N, activation='relu') layer, as in the original post, to an LSTM(N, activation='relu/sigmoid')? 

Thus, when using, for example, train_on_batch in keras my input and output shapes would also remain same as in my initial attempt?

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I was suggesting! I updated my answer to show how you could use an LSTM preserving your input and output shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely convenient solution. I'm trying it right now, and I notice that monotonicity has been strictly enforced! The nn output doesn't fit the required curve accurately anymore, but I think I've found a reason for this--namely that my y_train isn't always strictly increasing from element to element (here left-to-right) instead it looks like this sometimes: [0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.51, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,0.75, 0.9, 1.]. Would increasing the window over which one looks back (now just by one element) help, you think? Or is there any other LSTM-based trick one can use in this situation?

Comment: You're welcome! I am not sure why the output doesn't fit the curve accurately anymore (I assume you are undoing the transformation of the output representation). Just to make it clear, the first parameter of the LSTM doesn't indicate the window over which one looks back, but rather the dimensionality of the hidden state. I updated my answer with a suggestion

Comment: Yes, it's definitely undoing the transformation. Chaining LSTM layers does not work for the problem so far and, in fact, if I increase the number of elements in the required sequence, outputs start going to nan as well (with and without multiple LSTM layers). 

However, as I mentioned above, there are  many cases in my data where the sequences aren't strictly monotonic (ie y[i] may be equal to y[i+1]), and maybe this is also an issue.

Comment: I don't see why this could be an issue, because the network should easily be able to output 0 when y[i] == y[i+1] as the output activation is a ReLU. I'm unsure about what could be going on. I'm afraid I can't provide more help here.